# RESTEASY004655 When I generate a larger PDF file

Tags: java, resteasy, rest

I have a java EE application with a web part and a server part. I enter data into the web part and the server processes it and returns a PDF document.

I use this api:

```
@Path("pdf")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response generatePDF(Doc d);
```

I send the document as JSON, which can include uploaded attachments.
However, if the JSON contains multiple files and I exceed a certain size, I get:

```
[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec] (default task-1) I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8089: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec] (default task-1) Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8089
```

and

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
```

This works great for documents with small content. What should I change to make it work for documents that exceed about 8 MB? The implementation of the method generatePDF(Doc d) does not run at all.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Complete Log:

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:246)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:362)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:618)
        at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
        at Bean$$$view21.getPDF(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
        at Bean$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getPDF(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:311)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:115)
        at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:58)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:96)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:839)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.generated.FaviconErrorHandler.handleRequest(FaviconErrorHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:321)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:439)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:148)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy220.generatePDF(Unknown Source)
at Bean.getPDF(Bean.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
        ... 116 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingOutputStream.write(LoggingOutputStream.java:74)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:136)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113)
        at org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.writeTo(FileEntity.java:99)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:160)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:317)
        ... 151 more
```

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error on local machine, and Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) on server. That's what I just noticed.

Comment: The errors you show are just the result of the request failing. Somewhere in your server logs you should hopefully have an exception that tells you the underlying reason. If file size is an important factor then chances are that you run out of memory due to holding onto unnecessary stuff. Search for those exceptions and post them here.

Comment: The log on the server is clean. This happens when attachments exceed some limit, but the number of attachments doesn't matter. Would it help to attach a complete error message from the site side?

Comment: Of course a complete stack trace would help, but didn't you just say the log is clean?

Comment: I have two logs. One for the web side and one for the server side of the application. Server side is clean, web not.

Comment: I have added the complete log.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, you can configure your RESTEasy with specific timeouts and increase them to see if you can pass this limitation or not.

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.0.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html

The RestEasyclientBuilder has 2 methods for handling timeouts:

> ```
> The connectTimeout method replaces the establishConnectionTimeout method.
>
> The connectTimeout method determines how long the client must wait when making a new server connection.
>
> The readTimeout method replaces the socketTimeout method.
>
> The readTimeout method determines how long the client must wait for a response from the server.
> ```

Example:

```
new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
            .register(ClientRestLoggingFilter.class)
            .register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
```

**Setting the value of the timeout parameter to zero causes the server to wait indefinitely.**

---

Another point to consider is if your application is deployed on a server and that server can have its own timeouts configured and could easily cut the REST connection if it sees it passes a specific timeout.

-- Edited --

Enable RestEasy tracing and see if we can find at what point it fails during sending.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-tracing-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I set: ResteasyWebTarget target = (ResteasyWebTarget) new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).register(commonResteasyJackson2Provider).build().target(properties.getServerApiUrl()); and result is same:  ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component Bean for method public byte[] Bean.getPDF(Document) throws java.io.IOException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request

Comment: Can you please enable resteasy tracing? @MartinHofman 
https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.0.0.Final/userguide/html/Tracing_Feature.html

Comment: I added the library, set it up, but nothing new in the log.

Comment: I have solution:

undertow:
    servers:
      default-server:
        http-listeners:
          default:
            max-post-size: 104857600

configure in .yml file